# Term Frequency per Field over all indexed Documents in Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I'm looking for a way to find the term frequencies over similar fields in Lucene.

Let's say my fields are the following for a given Document:

Document1:

/movie/actor/name0: Tom
/movie/actor/name1: Tom Tom
/movie/actor/name2: Tom Tom Tom

/movie/actor/nickname0: Tom Tom Tom
/movie/actor/nickname1: Tom Tom

Document2 :

/movie/actor/name0: Tom Tom Tom
/movie/actor/name1: Tom

/movie/actor/nickname0: Tom

Document 3:

/movie/actor/name0: Tom

/movie/actor/nickname0: Tom Tom
/movie/actor/nickname1: Tom Tom Tom

I want the following output:

/movie/actor/name: 16 (sum over all types of nameX)

/movie/actor/nickname: 11 (same algorithm as above).

I have a way to iterate through all of the nicknameX and nameX efficiently, so I don't need help there. I need help in finding the term frequencies.

Right now, for a given field (say /movie/actor/name), I first create a new termdocs, go through /movie/actor/name0 , ... , /movie/actor/namen, create a new term with the ith fieldname and the given field value (in the above example the field value was "tom"), set the term for the termdocs to that term, and iterate through each document computing freq()

explicitly (for one field):

```
TermDocs td = is.getIndexReader().termDocs();
for(int i=tmp2; i<=tmp; i++){
      Term thisterm = new Term(distinctf[i], fv);
      td.seek(thisterm);
      while(td.next()){ //loop through <document, frequency> enumeration (all docs in collection)
          sum+=td.freq();
      }
  }
return sum;
```

distinct[i] is the ith distinct field (e.g. /movie/actor/namei)

Thank you!